# Setting or Remembering Zoom Level

Tags: remote-desktop

is there a way to edit the rdp file to set the zoom level?

or is there a way to make Remote desktop remember the zoom level you select with the GUI?

Comment: Zoom level - you mean the size of the RDP session window?

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, yes.

Open the Remote Desktop Connection window (`mstsc`), and go to the Display tab. Here you can specify the resolution of the remote desktop window.

[image]

Smart-sizing will always persist, too. You can find the smart sizing option by right-clicking on the top bar of the RDP window.

[image]

Comment: +1 this is how I set remote sessions.

Comment: I see your +1, and raise you +1

Comment: i specify the res in the RDP file as the one i want 1600x1500 (I was using 1600x1200 before) is not an option on the slider.  I run it on my notebook with a 2.8k screen, so 100% is small. I think smart sizing is no good for me as I need to be able to scroll vertically past the height of my screen - maybe about 400px of my window is not shown onscreen when zoomed to 150%, but the entire width is. It might sound sloppy but I actually want to only see this part of the RDP window most of the time, occasionally scrolling down to the less important off-window area when I need to.

Comment: are there any third party RDP clients with a more fine-grained control over the zoom level?

Comment: You could have a look at VNC or TeamViewer